# lucene.net search & order search result by hit.score c#

Tags: c#, lucene.net

i was finding code to search index data by lucene.net. i got a code from this url
http://www.eggheadcafe.com/tutorials/csharp/c69ef65f-e3c6-409e-ab97-168897c74f83/lucenenet-indexing-searching-entry-level-tutorial.aspx

here is small sample code.

```
List<SearchResult> list = new List<SearchResult>();
SearchResult sr = null;
for (int i = 0; i < results; i++)
{
    sr = new SearchResult();
    Document doc = hits.Doc(i);
    float score = hits.Score(i);
    sr.Id = int.Parse(doc.Get("id"));
    sr.Score = score;
    sr.Description = doc.Get("Description");
    sr.Title = doc.Get("Title");
    sr.Link = doc.Get("Link");
    list.Add(sr);
}
//sort by score
list = list.OrderByDescending(x => x.Score).ToList();
```

one thing is not clear to me that what is **hit.score?**
why result set is sorted by **hit.score** in descending order?

i search the index through above code and code is working. i input **"audi jcb"** for search and i saw six search data come for audi and one data come for jcb but jcb data comes at top....i just do not understand why. i want to show those data at top which will have maximum search result. for that is change the code bit like

```
list = list.OrderBy(x => x.Score).ToList();
```

i search by ascending but still not getting the result the way i want....audi data is not coming at top. so guide me what to incorporate in my code as result those data come at top which will have maximum occurrence in search result set. please guide me thanks.

Comment: lucene's score is complex, heres a link to the formula: http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/2_9_4/api/all/org/apache/lucene/search/Similarity.html

Comment: And results are sorted by score by default.

Answer (score 0):

Score is an indicator of the relevancy of the document to your query.  The higher the score, the more likely the document is relevant.

It's hard for me to say why jcb documents are outscoring audi document without knowing more about your dataset.  If all else was equal in terms of the occurrences of the keywords within your documents, I would guess that jcb is less common of a term than audi.  Terms with lesser frequency are weighted higher since they are more likely to be what you are looking for if you happen to match on a rare term.

The problem with you getting identical results using 2 different sorts could be 2 things that I can think of.  One would be some sort of mistake on your part.  Two would be if all the results had identical scores.

Can you check the scores of your results?